# Account for technical replicates in caret

Tags: r, machine-learning, regression, cross-validation, r-caret

I'm currently working on a project in which we want to identify treatments that correspond to a certain level of outcome (regression). The project has the following structure. There are 35 unique treatment methods that are applied in random combinations of 5 treatments each. Each combination is applied in 4 technical replicates. There are a total of 150 such combinations. 100 for training and 50 for testing. We want to know of any single treatment or combination of treatments will enable us to predict the level of outcome.

The structure of the data is

Mix ID | Outcome | Treatment 1 | Treatment 2 | ... | Treatment 35

Where any Mix ID is present 4 times (technical replicates) and the presence of the treatment is denoted by 0 or 1 (present or absent).

So far I have taken the median of the technical replicates for every combo to train the algorithm, but someone in the group suggested that I should consider each technical replicate as a single data point as they are not 100% identical. However, when using `repeatedcv`, it will randomly select data points for the training and validation set, including technical from the same treatment. I fear that having the same treatment combos in both sets is sub-optimal. Does anyone know how to tell caret to never "split" data from the same treatment condition (never have the same Mix ID in both training and validation set)?

An example is

```
control <- trainControl(method='repeatedcv', 
                        number=4, 
                        repeats=20)

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Build a general linear model
glm_model <- train(y = y, 
                  x = x,
                  method = 'glm',
                  metric = 'RMSE',
                  trControl = control)

example of training data:

     Mix Leaf15 Leaf21 Leaf32 Leaf68 Leaf70 Leaf76 Leaf82 Leaf88 Leaf122 Leaf126 Leaf161 Leaf168 Leaf176 Leaf182 Leaf183 Leaf187 Leaf189 Leaf203 Leaf220 Leaf225 Leaf226 Leaf254 Leaf289 Leaf299 Leaf314 Leaf337 Leaf339 Leaf354 Leaf361
1 axenic      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
2   Mix1      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0       0       0       0       0       1       0       0       1       1       0       0       0       0       1       0       0       0       0       1       0       0
3   Mix2      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      1       1       0       0       0       1       0       0       0       1       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
4   Mix3      0      0      1      0      0      1      0      0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       1       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       1
5   Mix4      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      1       0       1       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       1       0       0       0       0       0       1       0       0       0       0       1
  Leaf371 Leaf380 Leaf405 Leaf416 Leaf454 Leaf466
1       0       0       0       0       0       0
2       0       0       0       0       0       0
3       0       0       0       0       1       0
4       0       0       1       0       0       0
5       0       0       0       0       0       0
```

dput version

```
structure(list(Mix = c("axenic", "Mix1", "Mix2", "Mix3", "Mix4"
), Leaf15 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Leaf21 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L), Leaf32 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), Leaf68 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L), Leaf70 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Leaf76 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L), Leaf82 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Leaf88 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L), Leaf122 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), Leaf126 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L), Leaf161 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Leaf168 = c(0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), Leaf176 = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), Leaf182 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Leaf183 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Leaf187 = c(0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Leaf189 = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L), Leaf203 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), Leaf220 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Leaf225 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Leaf226 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Leaf254 = c(0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Leaf289 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Leaf299 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), Leaf314 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Leaf337 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Leaf339 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Leaf354 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Leaf361 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), Leaf371 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Leaf380 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Leaf405 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), Leaf416 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Leaf454 = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), Leaf466 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 
5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you please `dput` an example of your dataset, or create a reproducible example to work with. Meanwhile, you can take a look a  the `index` and `indexOut` arguments of `trainControl`. With those arguments, you can control which rows are included in which resampling set

Comment: I added some example. Thanks. I will have a look into index. I guess I could use the `Mix` ID as an index.

Comment: block CV is appropriate here. Here is a [blog post](https://mlr3gallery.mlr-org.com/posts/2020-03-30-stratification-blocking/) explaining what it is. In caret you can create predefined folds to  account for the technical replicates and specify them via `index` argument in `trainControl` as Elia mentioned.

Comment: I marked the answer as a duplicate since I trust topepos answer is enough to help you solve your problem. If you seek further help post a comment and I will consider reopening the question.

Comment: Thanks. I managed with the `index` argument and `createMultiFolds`.